# Use perl remove new lines from windows file in unix

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I am using perl on RH5.

I have a space delimited file output by Windows in this format:

> 24 header files
>
> A B1 C1
>
> B2 C2
>
> B3 C3
>
> B4 C4
>
> D E1 F1
>
> E2 F2...

For use in gnuplot and other plotting software ON WINDOWS (if it works on UNIX gnuplot, bonus points), I would like it in the form.

> A B1 C1 B2 C2 B3 C3 B4 C4
>
> D E1 F1 E2 F2 ...

After I searched stackoverflow, I found that need to use a substitution instead of chomp() because windows uses \r\n instead of just \n. As a result, I wrote this code.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $filename = 'windowsfile.dat';

open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";    #aborts if file does not exist

my $n = 0;  #line number counter
while (my $row = <$fh>){
    $n = $n + 1;
    if ($n > 24){   #skip header files
        if( ($n%4) != 0){  #Use modulus to take all but every 4th row.  
            $row =~ s/\r?\n/ /;    #removes Windows or Unix newline at end of read data
            #$row =~ s/\r/ /; #also tried this pair of commands
            #chomp($row);
        }
        print "$row\n";    #<---- turned out this was the mistake.There should not be a \n.
    } 

}
```

This does not work. When I view the file on VIM for Windows, I see:

> A B1 C1
>
> B2 C2
>
> B3 C3
>
> B4 C4^M

When I view on gedit on Unix, I also see the original format. When I try to plot the data, in gnuplot on Windows, I get a no data found error. When I plot it using gnuplot on UNIX, it plots like all of the carriage returns are still there. I'm guessing part of my problem is switching between platforms, but I don't understand why my code does not actually stop a newline from occurring.

Alternately, if you could tell my how to plot
A vs B1 and A vs C4 in gnuplot using the current format, that would be useful. The perl solution is nice though because it is easier in a variety of situations such as A vs. C4-B2 or use in other software.

Comment: First guess: your regex is only working once.  You need a g modifier:  $row =~ s/\r?\n/ /g;

Comment: `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` may be worth a look too.

Comment: `print $row;` instead of `print "$row\n";`?

Comment: Try: $row =~ s/[\r\n]/ /g; instead of $row =~ s/\r?\n/ /;

Comment: Thank you mpapec for being my 2nd set of eyes! I completely missed that. Sobrique, I will look into those, they sound useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may prefer this refactoring of you program.

- `use autodie` saves manually checking the status of the `open` call
- `use open` sets the default mode of all standard and newly-opened IO handles
- The `while` loop is made more concise by using the default `$_` to hold input lines
- There is a built-in line counter `$.` which you may as well use
- The executable substitution changes all trailing whitespace -- which includes CR and LF -- to either a space or a newline, according to whether `$. % 4` is zero.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.010;
use autodie;
use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

my $filename = 'windowsfile.dat';

open my $fh, '<', $filename;

while (<$fh>) {
  next unless $. > 24;
  s/\s+\z/ $. % 4 ? ' ' : "\n" /e;
  print;
}
```

**output**

```
A B1 C1 B2 C2 B3 C3 B4 C4
D E1 F1 E2 F2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local $/; $_ = <DATA>; $match=$_;
$match=~s/(\w+)\r*\n*\s+/${1} /gs;
$match=~s/([A-Z])\s/\n$1 /gs;
print $match;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. It's always better to explain what the code does and how it addresses the question. This helps future users.